# meaning of "if a day"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "if a day" in the following sentence?

> Young Fergus turned out to be seventy, if a day.

From John le Carré's The Secret Pilgrim.

Comment: It's a very compact form for something like the following train of thought: If he was even a day old (which is a given), then he was at least seventy years old. I.e, the writer intimates he is far over seventy years old.

Comment: Duplicate of [meaning of 'a century old if it was a day](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319273/meaning-of-a-century-old-if-it-was-a-day').

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic expression usually found when expressing  the age of someone; used to say that someone is at least a certain age.

If he is a day old (which is obviously true) then he is pushing seventy.

[If a day](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/if+a+day), if one's a day:

> Fig. a phrase attached to an expression of someone's age. *She's fifty if she's a day! I'm sure he's forty-five if he's a day.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

Comment: ... and the idiomatic expression means, "at the very least". So, "he's fifty, if he's a day" means, "He's obviously WAY more than a day old, and definitely at least fifty years"  (if we really want to unpack it all the way).